# Convert a vector to density vector in R

Tags: r, probability-density, auc

I have a vector

```
v = [..., -10, -10, -10, ..., 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, ...]
```

The `geom_density` plots the histogram of this vector in a smooth fashion, like a density function!

How can I use the `auc`, area under the curve, function of library `MESS`, to compute the areas under the curve for the density plot of such vector in a given interval, let say `(-1, 3)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"The geom_density plots the histogram of this vector in a smooth fashion, like a density function!*"
Well, that's because `geom_density` performs a [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)! So it's not *"like a density function"*, it *is* a density function.

Under the hood of `geom_density` it is actually `stats::density` that performs the density estimation. The kernel density estimates are given such that they define a proper probability density function with unit area under the curve.

We can confirm that by

```
x <- rnorm(100)
dens <- density(x)
df <- data.frame(x = dens$x, y = dens$y)
sum(df$y) * diff(df$x)[1]
#[1] 1.000952
```

Close enough.

It's straight-forward to integrate the density function over a specific range by summing the corresponding values in `df`; since you don't provide sample data I leave that up to you.

Comment: Thank you :D I figure that out meanwhile. 

It is the obsessed people who make the world an interesting place.

Cheers